# Expo and Admob: "Error Domain=com.google.admob Code=1 "Account not approved yet...."

Tags: react-native, admob, expo

I am trying to use `expo-ads-admob` with `Expo` but I am getting the following error: `Error Domain=com.google.admob Code=1 "Account not approved yet. <https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9905175#1>" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Account not approved yet. <https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9905175#1>`

The steps I have done:

1. Created an Admob account.
2. Create app for both ios and android.
3. Created Ad units for ios and android (it has been several hours).
   [image]

This is my code:

```
<AdMobBanner
  bannerSize="mediumRectangle"
  adUnitID={ Platform.OS === 'ios' ? "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx" : "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx" } // Test ID, Replace with your-admob-unit-id
  servePersonalizedAds
  onDidFailToReceiveAdWithError={(err) => console.log("error : ", err)}
/>
```

And this is my `app.json`.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "catch3",
    "slug": "catch3",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
      "config": {
        "googleMobileAdsAppId": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxx"
      }
    },
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "android": {
      "useNextNotificationsApi": true,
      "userInterfaceStyle": "dark",
      "config": {
        "googleMobileAdsAppId": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxx"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you confirmed that your account is actually approved?

Comment: @KenY-N Ach, of course not. No, not approved yet. Thanks.